# jQuery each increment issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, loops, each

++++++++++UPDATE++++++++++++++++

On further testing i found that a few times the attr method could not set the attributes. I changes the following line of code to make things simple:

`$(this).attr('name', 'yahoo');`

after the `afterRemoveCurrent` event was triggred, i `console.log` the `$(this)` on which the above line of code was supposed to execute and to my surprise the attribute was not changed to `yahoo`. I repeated this several times and observed that a few times the attribute was changed and other times it did not. I used `setTimeout` to delay the execution of the whole function inside `afterRemoveCurrent` by 500ms but still same results. This helps?

++++++++++UPDATED CONTENT ENDS ABOVE+++++++++++++++++++++++

I have this little piece of code which is not working as expected. I am using a plugin called sheepit http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB (Lets you add multiple form fields):

Live version of the page can be seen here:

The `i` in this statement `$(this).attr('name', 'rooms[' + i + ']' + '.' + arr[1] + '.' + arr[2]);` gets evaluated incorrectly sometimes. To be more specific:

The variable `i` should be same in the following 2 statments (each loop):

`$(this).attr('data-index', i);` and
`$(this).attr('name', 'rooms[' + i + ']' + '.' + arr[1] + '.' + arr[2]);`

But somehow a few times when the value of `i` is `0` in the first statement, it is `1` or some other number in 2nd statement.

```
var sheepItForm = $('#sheepItForm').sheepIt({
    separator: '',
    allowRemoveLast: false,
    allowRemoveCurrent: true,
    allowAdd: true,
    maxFormsCount: 8,
    minFormsCount: 1,
    iniFormsCount: 0,
    pregeneratedForms: ['pregenerated_form_1'],
    afterRemoveCurrent: function(source) {
        var i = 0;
        $('select.children').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('data-index', i);
            $(this).parent().find('select.child-age-option').each(function() {
                var arr = $(this).attr('name').split('.');
                $(this).attr('name', 'rooms[' + i + ']' + '.' + arr[1] + '.' + arr[2]);
            });
            i++;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure:

```
afterRemoveCurrent: function(source) {
    (function(i) {
        $('select.children').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('data-index', i);
            $(this).parent().find('select.child-age-option').each(function() {
                var arr = $(this).attr('name').split('.');
                $(this).attr('name', 'rooms[' + i + ']' + '.' + arr[1] + '.' + arr[2]);
            });
            i++;
        });
    })(0);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the `i` variable in your code is being affected by some other code in the same scope. This closure means that the variable passed in as `i` - the `0` - is only available within this code block.

Comment: Hopefully this should make it a little clearer: with closure: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cGBmN/, without: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cGBmN/1/. Note the difference in the console.

Comment: thank you Rory. I do understand scopes (thanks for the fiddles) but i think this is not related to the scope. I tried your code, same results. I changes the variable name to something that is not being used else where in my code, same results. If on the live page, you can open the console and type `$('select.child-age-option')` and see the results.. then `add a few rooms` again type `$('select.child-age-option')` in console and check results.. now remove a room and then add another room and then type `$('select.child-age-option')` again to see the results. Notice the `name` attribute each time

Comment: Sorry, please select `children` before u type anything in the console.. do the same for each added form fields set. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sheepItForm = $('#sheepItForm').sheepIt({
    separator: '',
    allowRemoveLast: false,
    allowRemoveCurrent: true,
    allowAdd: true,
    maxFormsCount: 8,
    minFormsCount: 1,
    iniFormsCount: 0,
    pregeneratedForms: ['pregenerated_form_1'],
    afterRemoveCurrent: function(source) {
        $('select.children').each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr('data-index', i);
            $(this).parent().find('select.child-age-option').each(function() {
                var arr = $(this).attr('name').split('.');
                $(this).attr('name', 'rooms[' + i + ']' + '.' + arr[1] + '.' + arr[2]);
            });
        });
    }
});
```